# MS Access richtext textbox formatting menu from VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a richtext textbox control that works nicely enough.  I can change the formatting of the text if I use the mouse to select some text--then the contextual formatting menu appears and I can select the various formats that I want (e.g., bold, ital., highlighting color, text color, etc.).

However, I'd like the formatting menu to appear at other time, for example, on right-click, or, when text is selected using cursor keys, or, when some key combination or command button is clicked.

I've searched for how to use VBA to bring up the formatting context menu but have found nothing.

**Anyone know the VBA code to bring up the formatting context menu for a MS Access richtext textbox control?**

Answer (score 2):

That is not possible I'm afraid.

Two common solutions are adding the formatting options to the ribbon, and creating your own custom formatting menu, in combination with hotkeys. (Some already present, such as `Ctrl-b` for bold.)

Let me know if you need any help with either direction.

Comment: OK.  I was afraid of that.  Thanks, @JCro.  I do have a few keyboard shortcuts already programmed, but it gets dicey with rich text to get the correct formatting at the correct spots.  Still, looks like I'll need to go in that direction.